# Acessing a value on an ArrayFire array

Tags: arrayfire

I had a af::array and need to acess the value in a row, like z(8), e.g.
But, when i try to do this, in a loop with a incremental i, the compiler returns

```
    cannot convert from 'af::array::array_proxy' to 'double'
```

Someone knows how can I acess the value inside the array?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `scalar` in the arrayfire documentation [here](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__method__mat.htm#ga5400245c298ffb4d790d846fa97f0e6a).

For your use case, you can access the element like this :

```cpp
float val = z(8).scalar<float>();
```

Could you talk about why you need to do this? In many cases, transferring values to the host from the GPU is unnecessary and avoidable.