# How do I convert an Arrayfire Array to a Rust Vec?

Tags: rust, arrayfire

I'm new to Rust (and Arrayfire) and working on a small project. I'm trying to convert an Arrayfire Array (only real) back to a Rust Vec.

After some research, I wasn't able to find a solution. The Rust Arrayfire documentation section to indexing only shows (as far as I can see) methods which return another Array.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684155/acessing-a-value-on-an-arrayfire-array) talking about the C++ Arrayfire but the Rust Arrayfire Array does not implement the indexing trait.

Is there a way to convert an an Arrayfire Array to a Rust Vec or a method to index an Array returning one element (for example one i64) like v[0] does?

Comment: Why on earth would somebody vote to close this as opinion-based?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the `host` function of `Array`. Something like this should work:

```
let mut buffer = Vec::<f64>::new();
buffer.resize(ar.elements());
ar.host(&mut buffer);
// Buffer now contains a copy of the data.
```